# go install: no install location for directory

Tags: git, go

I get the error `go install: no install location for directory`.

My `$GOPATH` environment variable is set just fine. The issue I have is that I don't want to develop inside my go workspace. Or is this my only choice?

I have a git repo sitting somewhere else and I would like to work inside there, if the binaries are compiled into the `$GOPATH` that is fine - but I'd expect to be able to compile / run builds from an arbitrary directory.

I wouldn't expect another collaborator to have to clone the repo into their go workspace? That seems like a serious limitation to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Either:

1. Change your GOPATH
2. Add more entries to GOPATH
3. Don't compile with go, but the compiler and linker themself

> I wouldn't expect another collaborator to have to clone the repo into their go workspace? That seems like a serious limitation to me.

It is not. That is exactly what a "go workspace" is for.

Comment: I guess the go workspace namespaces your go projects to others. I just don't like the idea of a forced convention. Something to get used to!

Comment: I haven't tried it out by I believe a softlink would work well too. Can somebody confirm and maybe add it to your list?

Comment: I could really use more detail out of this answer... 1) changing gopath means my root installed packages aren't found. 2) more entries doesn't seem to be achieved with a colon like normal export PATH=/and/this/path:$PATH Finally, 3) How?

Comment: @WrayBowling 1) GOPATH and GOROOT are completely decoupled. Changing GOPATH has absolutely no influence on your stdlib packages under GOROOT. (Or what are your "root installed packages"?) Remember to _never_ install non standard lib packages in GOROOT. 2) More entries work, either ':' separated (Unix) or ';' separated (Windows). Note that `go get` installs into the first entry of GOPATH. Running `go help gopath` is a good idea.

Comment: @WrayBowling 3) Run `go tool` to see compiler, linker, assembler etc and check the command documentation on golang.org. Option 3 is for experts or people you cannot live with a sane standard way of doing thing because they _need_ the hard and unconventional way. For the RTFM should be okay, especially as the inline help (`go help` et al.) and the online documentation are really good.